# Modeling and animating bow-tie knotting

Tags: animation, bones, snapping

I'm trying to model and animate the tying of a bow-tie.

I'm using an armature to deform a mesh for the bow-tie. My biggest trouble is controlling the armature carefully enough to get a good result, especially the knot itself.

This is a part of the animation:

[image]

I thought I might use some simple meshes as guides to which I could snap individual bones. But it looks like bone snapping in Pose mode adds inherited rotation. For example, trying to snap a bone to an edge doesn't put it *on* the edge (since the bone inherits rotation from its parent):

[image]

If I disinherit the parent rotation, I can snap right to the edge, but then re-inheriting the bone moves it away again.

Is there a better way to do any of this?

Comment: Update: Some things I have learned so far:
1. Use bones for animation
2. Use rotate w/individual origins to make loops
3. Use more bones and shrink to scrunch the tie in knots.
4. Selectively hide bones to focus on overlapping stuff in knots.
5. Selectively subdivide bones where tight turns are needed (reapply parenting every time!)

Comment: Update: Another tip for others... When animating multiple bones and their motion together strays outside what you want during the keyframe interval, use the f-curve editor to adjust how the individual bones move.